# How to diagnose issue with browsing websites?

Tags: windows-10, networking, firefox, tcpip

I've had an issue with my PC which started yesterday.

After reboot it works fine for about 10 minutes, then i'm unable to browse any websites from Firefox, Chrome or Edge. Rebooting again fixes it for another ~10 minutes.

I'm able to ping the sites by IP and hostname at all times.

In safe mode everything works properly.

My first thought was some kind of malware trying to proxy the connection, but ESET and Malwarebytes both show a clean scan.

I tried changing my internal IP, also tried disabling my network adapter and installing a USB-ethernet one, no effect.

Any help appreciated as to what to try next to fix it.

Comment: Do any other applications misbehave or stutter after running the computer for a little while? Specifically any graphically intensive programs or apps that use hardware acceleration. Try Chrome with hardware acceleration disabled.

Comment: *"I'm unable to browse any websites from Firefox, Chrome or Edge."* - What exactly is the issue you are encountering? What do you do and what is the result?

Comment: Is there sufficient disk space for the browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

What I sometimes found was that the OS was making some large downloads from the vendor's sites and this simply blocked other traffic due to bandwidth limitations.

To diagnose you could try to monitor connections on your router - given that it has that function. This way you could see that some traffic is actually happening and which. And to stop it (at least for testing) it then could be an idea to block that kind of traffic within the router.

Answer (score 0):

I've been recently struggling with exactly the same problem. I searched the web for around two weeks and tried literally every possible solution I found, to no avail.

Finally, uninstalling the antivirus (ESET NOD32) did the trick for me, as suggested in [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-el-wifi-se-desconecta/984dfa6a-05d4-42cc-99c2-aa57de7b9965) on the Microsoft Community forums (in Spanish).

Answer (score 0):

Some antivirus programs, like Avast, Bitdefender, Eset Nod32, etc., mostly cause this problem. Uninstall antiviruses and restart the system. If the Internet connection works fine after restarting, reinstall your antivirus and check again. If the connection error appears again, run the network connection troubleshooter. Hope it will solve your issue